# Working with nested objects in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

Say I have a hash where a nested property could change.

```
"key1": {
  "prop1": {
    "subprop1": "could_change"
  }
}
```

If I get sent the info that `prop1.subprop1` has changed can I preform atomic updates on this property? Right now `node_redis` saves `prop1` as a string that says `'[object Object]'`. If I JSON.stringify() the obj then I would need to retrieve the object, parse to object in memory, make the edit, and then stringify and save the object -- not knowing if something has changed in the mean time.

If I should be working with this data in a different way could someone please explain? I have an object with may nested attributes that I need to be able to update parts of, in addition to needing to retrieve as a whole object.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

Lua scripting or a lock pattern would solve your problem.

```
EVAL 'local obj = cjson.decode(redis.call("GET", "key1")); obj.prop1.subprop1 = ARGV[1]; redis.call("SET", "key1", cjson.encode(obj));' 0 "did_change"
```

You could even make something more advanced in Lua for editing any key's JSON subobjects if you wanted to.

Look at the [Redis SETNX command docs](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) for an example of how to use a lock.

Comment: Note: Lua scripting is only available with Redis 2.6 or better.