# Automatically move data from MySQL to Redis

Tags: php, mysql, yii, redis

I am building a bulk mailer app using which a user can upload a CSV file with around a million email ids which will be written to MySQL. Since reading a million email ids from MySQL would slow down the system, I would like to use redis for caching.

My question is, how can I copy email ids from MySQL to redis automatically when new email ids are added?

I have not worked on redis earlier so links to some tutorials would be appreciated.

P.S I am using yii framework to build this app.

Thanks

**Update**: Got it working by modifying the code given below. Created a script that fetches values from database and add data to redis via foreach loop.

```
   <?php
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->connect('127.0.0.1',6379);
    $redis->hmset('user:2',
    array('name' => 'Sally', 'salary' => 5000));
    $redis->hmset('user:3',
    array('name' => 'Bill', 'salary' => 6000));
    $uid = 3;
    $user = $redis->hgetall('user:'.$uid)
    // {name:'Bill',salary:6000}
    echo $user['salary']; // 6000
?>
```

Courtesy: CardinalPath.com

Comment: How will you know when a new email is added?

Comment: @crafter New emails will be uploaded by the user via a CSV file to Amazon S3 after which all email ids from Amazon S3 will be written to MySQL.

Comment: I'm not sure, but will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719629/redis-value-update

Comment: @crafter No worries, I got it working :)

Comment: how did you do? Can you please explain by creating an answer to your question? It will help others. Thanks.